# Difference between maven in eclipse and maven from apache?

Tags: maven, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am working in Java Selenium Automation developing the code in eclipse-oxygen IDE , I am able to create new maven project. Do I need to download and install maven again from apache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need it only if you want to use maven from the command line....

Comment: You can use the menu supplied by eclipse to use maven to update dependency, test etc.  But if others want to execute script, he can shoose to install Apache maven, rather than eclipse, then execute maven test by command line like: mvn test.  You can install both on machine and you can configure maven in eclipse to use the setting.xml from apache maven.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification , kindly let me know 
is it mandatory to install maven from Apache POI to run the test using jenkins?

Comment: I don't understand, why do you need Apache POI?  Anyway, in Jenkins you need maven only if you have to build a maven project. So, if you plan to run your tests using maven, maven is required...

Comment: Sorry it is not Apache POI I was referring to Apache Maven. Just want to check if my understanding is right - So for running my scripts using  jenkins I need to install apache maven .